# Get AD attribute using .net 1.1

Tags: .net, vb.net, active-directory, ldap

This below code works perfectly in vb 2005 but can't work in .net 1.1.

```
Private Function GetActiveDirUserDetails(ByVal username As String) As String
        Dim dirEntry As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
        Dim dirSearcher As System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
        Try
            dirEntry = New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://123.45.67.89:101/DC=mydomain,DC=com")
            dirSearcher = New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
            dirSearcher.Filter = "(samAccountName=" & username & ")"
            Dim sr As DirectoryServices.SearchResult = dirSearcher.FindOne()
            If sr Is Nothing Then
                Return False
            End If

            Dim de As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = sr.GetDirectoryEntry()
            'Dim firstname = de.Properties("GivenName").Value.ToString()
            'Dim lastname = de.Properties("sn").Value.ToString()
            'Dim fullname = de.Properties("DisplayName").Value.ToString()

            Dim ObjFirstName As String = ""
            Dim ObjLastName As String = String.Empty
            Dim ObjEmail As String = ""

            Try
                ObjEmail = de.Properties("mail").Value.ToString()
                ObjFirstName = de.Properties("GivenName").Value.ToString()
                ObjLastName = de.Properties("sn").Value.ToString()

            Catch ex As Exception
                ObjFirstName = de.Properties("DisplayName").Value.ToString()
            End Try

            MsgBox(ObjFirstName + ObjLastName + ObjEmail)
            Return ObjFirstName
            Return ObjLastName
            Return ObjEmail

        Catch ex As Exception ' return false if exception occurs 
            Return ex.Message
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
```

When I press the button, it shows nothing. I am trying to get AD attributes here. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be loading any properties, i.e.

```
dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail")
dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("GivenName")
dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn")
```

Answer (score 0):

If target framework in VB was different with 1.1 (by default it is 2.0) then change it in the project properties to 1.1, get rid of try..catch and run the code again to ensure that it works "in VB". If it would work - then the problem is most likely not in .net version but it the way you run your application "outside of VB". For example, by default, when debugging a code on your local dev box you run the code under your account that might be different with an account which will be used to run the compiled application. In this case the code which is using AD might fail because it either using another user account (e.g. machine account instead of user account, or has less permissions in AD).

Comment: Thank you. Seems like the problem is about privilege in AD. I tried to access user info from different domain, it's impossible isn it? I think I have to join the domain

Comment: It depends on AD setup (if domains have trust). You need to check it with your AD admin as this is not related to VB but to AD configuration.